# How to split string into dictionary and separate words/sentences from urls keeping the string order

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split

I have a string with text and number of URL instances within the string. As myString is a variable, each time there can be none, one or multiple URL instances in different parts of myString and I'm looking to split myString into multiple messages only if there is any URL. Otherwise it would be just one message.

I'm looking for a way to separate text words/sentences in myString from URLs but keep order like within a conversation, for example:

```
message1: Text: "Hello world,"
message2: URL: "https://auth.geeksforgeeks.org/user/Chinmoy%20Lenka/articles"
message3: Text: "in the portal of"
message4: URL: "http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"
message5: Text: ". Sample text goes here"
... #and so on...
```

I assume I would need to convert my string into a nested dictionary, but not exactly sure how to achieve this. Could someone give me some tips? thank you in advance.

```
myString = "Hello world, https://auth.geeksforgeeks.org/user/Chinmoy%20Lenka/articles in the portal of http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/. Sample text goes here www.google.com but also here https://google.com lorem ipsum google.com/contact-us multiple urls within text."
```

Comment: This ```message4: URL: "http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"``` is not a valid dictionary in python

Comment: Why do you think a dictionary would be the best data structure? It appears that a list would be much more suitable since it keeps the order of elements, and your dictionary keys are effectively only the string 'message' + an index.

Comment: Regarding your problem, I'd google for a regular expression for URLs and use that to split the string into the individual URL/non URL parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = myString.split(" ")
urls = [];

for x in text:
    if x.find("http") != -1:
        urls.append(x)
```

And then just print every other entry of each list.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string word by word and store in the list. Then while iterating through that list, check whether current word is url or not. If it is, add it to the final list, else store it in `temp_words_list`. Here's code implementation:

```
def modifier(myString):
    words_list = myString.split()
    final_list = []
    temp_words_list = []

    for word in words_list:
        # assuming every word starting with http is actual url
        if '.com' in word or word.startswith('http'):
            if len(temp_words_list) > 0:
                final_list.append(' '.join(temp_words_list))
                temp_words_list = []
        
            final_list.append(word)
        else:
            temp_words_list.append(word)

    # Handling edge case when string does not end with url
    if len(temp_words_list) > 0:
        final_list.append(' '.join(temp_words_list))

    return final_list

print(modifier(myString))
```

This will give output of:

```
['Hello world,', 'https://auth.geeksforgeeks.org/user/Chinmoy%20Lenka/articles', 'in the portal of', 'http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/.', 'Sample text goes here', 'www.google.com', 'but also here', 'https://google.com', 'lorem ipsum', 'google.com/contact-us', 'multiple urls within text.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` from `re` module:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s*(https?://[^\s]*)\s*', myString)

['Hello world,',
 'https://auth.geeksforgeeks.org/user/Chinmoy%20Lenka/articles',
 'in the portal of',
 'http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/.',  # <- The problem is here (with '.')
 'Sample text goes here www.google.com but also here',
 'https://google.com',
 'lorem ipsum google.com/contact-us multiple urls within text.']
```